# Uneven door jam causing gap

Tags: doors, jamb

There's an uneven gap from the door knob side towards the door jam. The gap increases towards the section where the door knob/lock is but on top and bottom the reveal is wider.

It's almost like it was sanded in the middle or a bad piece of wood was used. Is there any way to add material to the jamb without replacing it? Like a cover or plate to fill in the gap and make it more uniform? [image: door1][image: door2]

Comment: A photo from an angle with the door open would really clear things up.

Comment: I'll take one when I'm home. But best I can describe is the "reveal" of the jamb isn't level it's wavy all along the mid section causing a big gap to the door

Comment: Wood putty might be the answer if you just want to smooth it out. Wood putty is not for structural repairs. You would want to sand the paint off the area that needs to be filled and use a putty knife to fill in the low spots. When it dries, you can sand it flat and paint over it.

Comment: Would the wood putty be enough to lessen the gap from the striker plate to the latch? That's why was thinking of some kind of structural add on to the door jamb